# In CMT If I set Requires_New transactional attribute and throws system exception then client gets which exception?

Tags: transactions, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

For example,
If I call EJB method from web context. EJB has Container Managed Transaction(CMT) with Local Bean and its method has `required_new transactional` attribute.
What does client gets if EJB method throws System Exception?
I mean, transaction is rolled back. So, Does client gets `EJBTransactionRolledBackException` or simply `EJBException`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the EJB 3.1 specification, section 14.3.1 "Exceptions from a Session Bean’s Business Interface Methods and No-Interface", table 15 states that non-AppException thrown by a RequiresNew method results in the client receiving EJBException.  EJBTransactionException is intended to be thrown when the EJB method runs using the caller's transaction, and the EJB container has marked the transaction for rollback due to the system exception.